# Swift: pattern for ViewController that can be acessed from many places

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns

In my app, I've a "details" screen/VC that can be accessed from 3 different screens.

I'm currently using constructor dependency injection and 3 different initializers to setup correct variables based on where user comes from.

Still, most of logic is in ViewDidLoad under pretty ugly ifs

Wrote a little sample to give you an idea of how it looks like now:

```
if object != nil {

    WebApi.fetchDropDown1 { items in
        dropdown.selectedItem = items.first{$0.id == object.UnitId}
    }

    currentDateLabel = object.date
} else if object == nil && currentDate == nil {
    // came to add from list of objects

    // object doesn't exist yet

    WebApi.fetchDropDown1 { items in
        dropdown.selectedItem = items[0] // select first availabile
    }

    currentDateLabel = Date() // set today as default date
    deleteButton.isEnabled = false
    // something like that for every element

} else if { currentDate != nil && object == nil} {
    // came here from calendar pick

    WebApi.fetchDropDown1 { items in
        dropdown.selectedItem = items[0] // select first availabile
    }

    currentDateLabel = currentDate

}
```

This isn't actual code, but just to clarify what I'm trying to solve.

Many tutorials on design patterns just do the simplest use-cases and I haven't been able to find some useful advice for more complex cases.

Thanks.

Comment: so you need to write some code in `viewDidLoad()` based on from where the user is coming to this screen, correct?

Comment: Yes. I've initializers, I set the variables there. Then, in viewDidLoad, based on which variables are set and which are not, I actually setup UI, get stuff from server etc. It all works, it just doesn't look pretty and I feel like there must be a better way.

Comment: Have you looked at the Builder design pattern?

Comment: Have you considered adding a property called `originVC` that could be a string or an enum, storing where the user has come from? When a VC performs a segue to the VC in question, it can set `originVC` to some value. Then you can just check the value of `originVC`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `enum` for this use case.

You can declare a public enum outside the ViewController like this:

```
public enum InitialiserType {
    case typeOne
    case typeTwo
    case defaultType
}
```

Create a property in your ViewController like this:

```
initialiserType:InitialiserType = .defaultType
```

Setting it to default will make the default initialiser to be called if the type is not specified.

Also, Add the following code in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
switch self.initialiserType {
    case .typeOne:
        print("Do the custom code for type one here")
    case .typeTwo:
        print("Do the custom code for type two here")
    case .defaultType:
        print("Do the default code here")
}
```

Now when you initialise the Viewcontroller, just set this type:

```
controller.initialiserType = .typeOne
```

Based on the type you set here, the initialiser will work accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to have a view controller instead of each case, I had this problem in one of my apps, at first I handled different cases with one view controller, but when the project got bigger, the app maintenance was very hard.

Comment: Crossed my mind - but then, do I need a separate storyboard VC for each? because the design of it is more-or-less the same.

Differences are mainly
case 1: object exists, setup views using data from existing object

case 2: object doesn't exist, fetch list from remote server and select first as default

case 3: object doesn't exist, but some of information is already selected on previous screen and should be used here.